# PageSlidingTabStrip library not compiling in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface

This is the link to the library that I downloaded from github.

https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip

I did not run the .bat file. I have removed all Link Markers. 
The app is crashing

**Here is the error log :**

`05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample/com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample.MainActivity
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1880)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:592)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.sample.MainActivity
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1025)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1871)
05-03 16:19:29.348: E/AndroidRuntime(3973):     ... 11 more`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problems. 
Make sure you have included the library into your main project. 
Then, your link shows that it needs the nineoldandroids library included too.Have you included that ?

also, make sure that you have marked the respective library projects as libraries